# QPSQL driver not loaded Qt

Tags: c++, qt, postgresql, qsqldatabase

I have some trouble when I want to add a database.

```
    _dataBase = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
```

After calling this method I have an error:

```
QSqlDatabase: QPSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7
```

I include to `PATH` variable paths to:

```
PostgreSQL\9.3\bin
PostgreSQL\9.3\lib
PostgreSQL\9.3\include
```

Also I copy folder `sqldrivers` to `Debug` folder. Also tried to copy dlls drom this folder to `Debug`. Doesn't work either.

Comment: Maybe use depends.exe on the psql driver to verify that it is pulling in the dlls that you have in PostgreSQL\9.3\bin

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks for reply:) I found that qsqlpsql.dll need libpq.dll from PostgreSQL\9.3\lib folder. I add this dll to Debug folder and now error message has gone:))) Many thanks:))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I came here googling because I had the same problem in Windows.

In my case to solve the issue I had to install PostgreSQL for Windows 32 bits since my Qt target was MinGW 32 bits.

Additionally, I had to add the `PATH` to the PostgreSQL bin and lib directories so Qt could find the right `.dlls`.

```
@SET PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.6\lib\;%PATH%
```

The `PATH` can be set before launching Qt Creator or using the Qt Creator itself via the `Build Environment` in the `Projects` pane.

Answer (score 12):

Add the system variable `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` if you want to get full information of why the `QPSQL` driver has not been loaded.

Probably you will discover that Qt is not able to find it. Copy and paste the output here to know what exactly happens.

Answer (score 3):

Use depends.exe on `qsqlpsql.dll` and found that this dll need `libpq.dll` from `PostgreSQL\9.3\lib`folder. Add `libpq.dll` to `Debug` folder and it works:)

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip install PyQt5` event if you already installed it using conda or installer. It helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem with deploying Qt application (windeployqt didn't help). I had to copy more .dlls (libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll, libiconv-2.dll, libintl-8.dll, libpq.dll, libssl-1_1-x64.dll, libwinpthread-1.dll) from postgreSQL bin path (c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin) next to .exe file (according to dependency walker).