# QT: driver not loaded, but driver is present

Tags: postgresql, qt, driver

## EDIT #2

It works, the first time I installed postgres 64bit, while Qt uses MinGW 32 bit.

## EDIT

Following the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26507353/qpsql-driver-not-loaded-qt) linked by [zapredelom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1005533/zapredelom), I installed postgres 9 and added to PATH the `bin` and `lib` directories. To be sure, I also restarted the machine, but nothing changed. `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` gives me no additional debug infos.

---

I get this error at runtime:

```
QSqlDatabase: QPSQL driver not loaded 
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7
```

As the error itself displays, postgres driver is already present. Indeed there's a `qsqlpsql.dll` and `qsqlpsqld.dll` under `C:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\plugins\sqldrivers`.
I have not built it and I have no Postgres installation on this machine (I test on my Linux OS and deploy on Windows 8.1 VM), the driver was already present after installing QT.

What's the problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26507353/qpsql-driver-not-loaded-qt did you tryed this aproach ?

Comment: @zapredelom: Now yes, and it does not work. See my updated answer.

Comment: @MarcoSulla Consider creating an answer yourself instead of adding it to your original question as an edit.

Answer (score 1):

The driver does not work because it does not find the dependency (it should be depends on libpq.dll), and when you run it, the plugin can not find the required dll. If you are using windows, just try to check using dependencywalker of the qsqlpsql.dll.

You can directly put your libpq.dll to your application exe folder.