# PostgreSQL driver does not load with PyQt5

Tags: postgresql, driver, pyqt5

I am having a problem when trying to connect to **PostgreSQL** from **PyQt5**, the following simple code gives me a

> *'Driver not loaded Driver not loaded"*

error message. I am newbie in this and have no idea what to do.

Here is the code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtSql

db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL")
print (db.lastError().text())
```

I'm using Python36 on Windows 10

Comment: What is the output of `print(QtSql.QSqlDatabase.drivers())`?

Comment: ['QSQLITE', 'QMYSQL', 'QMYSQL3', 'QODBC', 'QODBC3', 'QPSQL', 'QPSQL7']

Comment: Try some of the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26507353/984421).