# QSqlDatabase fail connection only when import module

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtsql

I have two modules in my project (using PyCharm 2018). The directory structure is:

```
> my_app (folder)
    > venv (folder)
    > database.py
    > my_app.py
    > libpq.dll
```

database.py creates the connection...

```
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase

hostName = "localhost"
databaseName = "my_app"
port = 5432
userName = "my_app_admin"
password = "****"


# Connect to database
def connect():
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL")
    db.setHostName(hostName)
    db.setDatabaseName(databaseName)
    db.setPort(port)
    db.setUserName(userName)
    db.setPassword(password)
    ok = db.open()
    print(db.lastError().text(), ok)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    connect()
```

When I run this module the connection is ok and the text printed is True (without error from lastError call).

But when I call database.connect() from my_app.py ...

```
import sys
import database
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
database.connect()
```

... the connection fails with the "Driver not loaded" error.

Why?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QPSQL driver not loaded Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26507353/qpsql-driver-not-loaded-qt)

Comment: It also adds the following: `import os` `os.environ['QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS'] = "1"` before `app = QApplication(sys.argv)` and check the message that appears in the console.

Comment: also adds the path of the directory where .dll is to the environment variables.

Comment: @eyllanesc thank you!