# How to install QPSQL drivers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, psql

I was trying to make connection to my `PSQL` database but when I checked:

```
dbliste = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.drivers()  print(dbliste),
```

i got this:

> ['QSQLITE', 'QODBC', 'QODBC3']

Why I don't have drivers for `QPSQL` installed? Where can I download them?

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtSql

def createConnection():
    db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL")
    db.setHostName('localhost') 
    db.setPort(5432) 
    db.setDatabaseName('DB_real') 
    db.setUserName('postgres') 
    db.setPassword('****') 


if not db.open():
    QtWidgets.QMessageBox.critical(None, "Cannot open database",
                         "Unable to establish a database connection.\n"

                         "Click Cancel to exit.", QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Cancel)
    return False

dbliste = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.drivers() 
print(dbliste)
```

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: My OS is win 10

Comment: try with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26507353/qpsql-driver-not-loaded-qt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution after two days is just to install 'Pyqt5' using pip even if is already installed with conda or installer:

```
pip install PyQt5
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that first problem was in different version of `PostgreSQL` and `QT`. Now I am deinstalling and installing the right versions and then I will try to connect it. I hope it works...

Comment: I tried, and no succes....
I added PATH, copied .dll, copied directory sqldrives and still nothing