# QPSQL driver not loaded (Qt6, Postgres-13)

Tags: qt, postgresql-13, qt6

I try to repeat [QPSQL driver not loaded Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26507353/qpsql-driver-not-loaded-qt) but it does not helped me. I used x64 Postgresql and my Qt application also x64

```
m_dataBase.addDatabase("QPSQL");
        m_dataBase.setHostName(g_hostName);
        m_dataBase.setPort(g_databasePort);
        m_dataBase.setDatabaseName(g_databaseName);
        m_dataBase.setUserName(g_userName);
        m_dataBase.setPassword(g_password);

        qInfo() << "drivers:" << m_dataBase.drivers();

        if( !m_dataBase.isDriverAvailable("QPSQL")) {
            qWarning() << "Driver QPSQL is not available";
        } else {
            qInfo() << "QPSQL is available";
        }

        if (m_dataBase.open()) {
            qInfo() << "Data base open SUCCESSFUL";
            return true;
        } else {
            qWarning() << "Data base does not open";
            qInfo() << "Last ERROR:" << m_dataBase.lastError().driverText();
        }
```

I enabled

```
qputenv("QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS", "1");
```

for editional debug logs.
I update PATH variable in cmd

```
SET PATH=D:\PostgresLib\lib;%PATH%
SET PATH=D:\PostgresLib\bin;%PATH%
```

and after what I see in output:

```
[06/05/2021 10:28:13.305] DBG        line:  QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "C:/Qt/6.0.3/mingw81_64/plugins/sqldrivers/qsqlpsql.dll"
[06/05/2021 10:28:13.306] WAR        line:  Found metadata in lib C:/Qt/6.0.3/mingw81_64/plugins/sqldrivers/qsqlpsql.dll, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QSqlDriverFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "QPSQL"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QPSQLDriverPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 393216
}


[06/05/2021 10:28:13.306] DBG        line:  Got keys from plugin meta data QList("QPSQL")
[06/05/2021 10:28:13.306] DBG        line:  QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "D:/Projects/Build/sqldrivers" ...
[06/05/2021 10:28:13.309] DBG        line:  loaded library "C:/Qt/6.0.3/mingw81_64/plugins/sqldrivers/qsqlpsql.dll"
[06/05/2021 10:28:13.309] INF   postgresdatabase.cpp    virtual bool PostgresDataBase::init() line:24   drivers: QList("QSQLITE", "QODBC", "QPSQL")
[06/05/2021 10:28:13.309] INF   postgresdatabase.cpp    virtual bool PostgresDataBase::init() line:29   QPSQL is available
[06/05/2021 10:28:13.309] WAR   postgresdatabase.cpp    virtual bool PostgresDataBase::init() line:36   Data base does not open
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in non initialized object QSqlDatabase m_dataBase;
fix:
instead of this string

```
m_dataBase.addDatabase("QPSQL");
```

I use

```
m_dataBase = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
```